# PL/SQL: Any common ancestor class?

Tags: oracle, class, inheritance, plsql, ancestor

Is there a common ancestor class in pl/sql?

For example, in Java the "Object" class is a common ancestor for all classes:

```
Object o;
o = new String("hi ancestor");          // a String is an Object
```

But in pl/sql we can't say:

```
o Object;                               // Object class doesn't exist
o := new myclass('hi ancestor');
```

---

**Update**: The question was more theoretical than practical, just to know if pl/sql had a common ancestor (root) class for all classes, since I didn't found anything on it in the documentation. The responses have confirmed that there is not such a common class. Anyway, I'm going to give some examples on how to simulate the common root class, based on the sugestions from the responses.

A way to do it is the trick given by Alex, by using the anydata type, that simulates the casting to a generic class. It can be useful to admit any class as parameter in functions. Example of use:

```
create or replace type cla as object    -- class
(
    name  varchar2(50)
);


declare
    co  cla;         -- cla class object
    co2 cla;         -- another one
    o   anydata;     -- Object class simulation object
    ok  pls_integer; -- to take value returned by the re-cast
begin
    co := new cla('hi');                -- create cla object
    o := anydata.convertobject(co);     -- cast to anydata (not automatic)
    ok := anydata.getobject(o, co2);    -- re-cast to cla

    dbms_output.put_line('co.name: '  || co.name);
    dbms_output.put_line('co2.name: ' || co2.name);
end;
```

Another way, proposed by user272735, is to simulate the common root class by creating a class that will be the parent of all of your root classes. For example:

```
create or replace type obj as object    -- Object class simulation
(
    oid  varchar2(1000)
)
not final;

create or replace type cla1  under obj  -- explicit inheritance
(
    name  varchar2(50)
);

create or replace type cla2  under obj  -- explicit inheritance
(
    money  number(6)
);


declare
    o1  cla1;       -- cla1 class object
    o1b cla1;       -- another one
    o2  cla2;       -- cla2 class object
    o2b cla2;       -- another one
    o   obj;        -- common ancestor
begin
    o1 := new cla1('1', 'hi');          -- create cla1 object
    o := o1;                            -- cast to obj (automatic)
    o1b := treat(o as cla1);            -- re-cast to cla1

    dbms_output.put_line('o1.name: '  || o1.name);
    dbms_output.put_line('o1b.name: ' || o1b.name);

    o2 := new cla2('2', 222);           -- create cla2 object
    o := o2;                            -- cast to obj (automatic)
    o2b := treat(o as cla2);            -- re-cast to cla2

    dbms_output.put_line('o2.money: '  || o2.money);
    dbms_output.put_line('o2b.money: ' || o2b.money);
end;
```

Comment: No. PL/SQL object model doesn't have such a class hierarchy root class like Java's `java.lang.Object`. You have to build it yourself if you need it.

Comment: See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ002) for Oracle docs on object relational coding.

Comment: @tbone thank you, I already knew that page :-)

Comment: @user272735 Thank you, I have used your suggestion in the examples (see the Update section of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so in the Java sense. You can sort of get something slightly similar with `ANYDATA`:

```
declare
  o anydata;
begin
  o := anydata.convertobject(myclass('hi ancestor'));
end;
/
```

You can read more [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=218), or of course in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_anydat.htm), but that doesn't have many examples. [Tom Kytes has talked about it too](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3099475696866).

But given your previous question, you might be better off storing Java classes in the database to do your object-oriented stuff through those, or move it out of the database entirely...

Comment: Well, I'm learning the oo capabilities of PL/SQL, and I'm just curious on how are implemented some things that exist in other oo languages, or how could be implemented. The anydata trick looks interesting and can be useful in some cases. Anyway I was looking for a common ancestor class that could be used polimorphically (for example, to assign to variables, to pass parameters, to run standard methods, etc).

Comment: @freesoft - you can pass anydata and anytype around; its main use case seems to be as a generic parameter. I haven't used it much though and there don't seem to be many examples around.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the examples, they look trickier than a real ancestor class. For example, it requires conversion (casting) in both directions (class->anydata and anydata->class), while a real ancestor only requires ancestor->class conversion (casting), the other one is automatic (due to polimorphism). Also, anydata doesn't have any method, since it is not a class, while a real ancestor has methods that are common to all classes (for example, in Java, the Object class has methods like clone(), equals(), toString(), etc). Anyway I'm marking your solution as accepted (can be useful in sometimes)